# Why is line break in a Windows batch file causing parenthesis not to be recognized?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I'm using Windows 10 version 1709.

I have a batch file with the following contents:

```
@echo off

dir nonexisting_file_or_dir || ^
(
    echo a
    echo b
)
echo c
```

What I'm getting is

```
File Not Found
'(' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
a
b
c
```

From questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/split-long-commands-in-multiple-lines-through-windows-batch-file), I understand that `^` allows for a line break, so why is the parenthesis not recognized?

Comment: This syntax does not make sense. You are mixing between batch/cmd and powershell or Linux. Study the subject first.

Comment: We demand on this site that posters make some effort to solve their problems before posting here. Your misunderstanding here is of subject matter that is trivial to find if searched for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are breaking the line using an unopened command block redirected by the **`||`** operator, is different from the link in your question, where it answers how to break the command line and does not apply to your command block.

```all-bat
:: Your command syntax ::
dir file ||  ^     ==>    your command   operator   unopened block
                            dir file       ||         ^

:: The syntax should be ::
dir file || ( ^    ==>    your command   operator   opened block   break line
                            dir file       ||         (              ^
```

```all-bat
:: The syntax trick should be ::
dir file || <nul ^ ==>    your command   operator   trick part   break line
                            dir file       ||         <nul           ^
```

- Command line:

```all-bat
dir /b nonexisting_file_or_dir || echo\command in one line && echo\another command
```

- Is the same:

```all-bat
dir /b nonexisting_file_or_dir || ^
echo\command in break line & echo\another command

::  Or...

dir /b nonexisting_file_or_dir ^
|| echo\command in break line && echo\another command

dir /b nonexisting_file_or_dir ^
|| (echo\command in break line & echo\another command)
```

- One block of commands using parentheses:

```all-bat
dir /b nonexisting_file_or_dir || ( 
echo\this is 
echo\your commands block 
echo\on the break line
)

echo\Try it...
```

- One block of commands using break line:

```all-bat
dir /b nonexisting_file_or_dir ^
 || echo\This is ^
 && echo/your command ^
 && echo/block ^
 && echo/on the ^
 && echo/break line ^
 && echo/You don't need (^)

echo\Try it...
```

> This may work to you by adding **`<nul`**...

```all-bat
@echo off

dir nonexisting_file_or_dir || <nul ^
(
    echo a
    echo b
)
echo c
```

- For details on **Operators'** behavior see: **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**